# Check if a record exist in a list with no explicit match

Tags: c#, list, switch-statement, mapping

What I mean is for example I have this list of language objects with Id and Code :

```
{ Id = 1, Code = "N" },
{ Id = 2, Code = "E" },
{ Id = 3, Code = "D" }
```

But I receive a language code in this format "NL", "EN", "DE".

What is the cleanest and easiest way to get the Id from the list?

I was trying to make a extension in the list :

```
public static int GetLanguageId(
        this IEnumerable<Language> languages,
        string languageCode)
    {
        switch (languageCode)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

int languageId = languageList.GetLanguageId(languageCode);
```

But I'm not sure how to. Any idea?

Comment: What's the rule? If N represents NL, what about Norwegian?

Comment: @shingo N => NL, E => EN and D => DE

Comment: If I understand well, you have a List<Language> list with Language being Class Language {public int Id {get;set;} string Code {get;set;}}
Then if you want the code from le string I'd use Linq:
listLanguage.FirstOrDefault(l=>l.Code==lnCode.Substring(0,1))?.Id??-1;
This should return the code or -1 if not found

Comment: So you can only cope with 26 languages? Why not just change your `N` to be `NL`?

Comment: @DavidG database data legacy

Comment: @user7849697 dont forget to close your post by validating the anwer you prefer.its like this SO is functionning

Answer (score 3):

you could use a dictionary in this case:

```
        var dico = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            {"N", 1 }, {"E", 2} , {"D", 3}
        };
        var langageCode = "NL";
        var id = dico[langageCode[0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply compare the first character

```
return languages.SingleOrDefault(lang => lang.Code[0] == languageCode[0]).Id;
```